# Content of child page doesn't show in tabbedpage (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin and XAML so i downloaded a sample solution which has 3 tabbed pages and each of them contains a child page. Each child page has a label with different text on it. I managed to write a program that is supposed to do the same thing, but the label doesn't show on any of the child pages. I can change the background color and title on the child pages.

Here's the code for the MainPage (TabPage):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MozaikMuzeum_Xamarin.View;assembly=MozaikMuzeum_Xamarin"
             x:Class="MozaikMuzeum_Xamarin.View.TabPage">

  <TabbedPage.Children>

    <pages:ActualPage />
    <pages:CatalogPage />
    <pages:BadgesPage />


  </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

And here's the code for one of the child pages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MozaikMuzeum_Xamarin.View.ActualPage" Title="Aktuális" BackgroundColor="Green">
  <Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
  <ContentPage.Content>

    <Label Text="Hi there from Page 1" TextColor="White" Font="20"
        VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: No label on the child page.]

As you can see the label doesn't show between the ContantPage.Content tags.

Comment: In the example of the child page you posted are actually two labels. Try to remove the one which is not inside the `Content`

Comment: Thank you, removing the label outside the content tags fixed it.